# What's the range of the TrueDepth camera?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, truedepth-camera

What's the minimum and maximum distance that the front facing TrueDepth camera can detect?

When [detecting depth data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/streaming_depth_data_from_the_truedepth_camera), if the value returned was normalized to the range 0 to 1, I'd be able to [convert it to a grayscale image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30958731/35690) pretty easily. However, since the values returned are distance in meters, I could easily get a value such as 2.5.

Therefore, knowing the theoretical minimum and maximum could help me normalize the values into the range of 0 to 1.

**Update:** Very inaccurate estimates using [Apple's sample app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65203758/whats-the-range-of-the-truedepth-camera) show that it's about 15cm (minimum) to 400cm (maximum), however, this measurement was nowhere near precise. Therefore, I'm still looking for a more authoritative answer (e.g. one that uses a better methodology for determining the range).